# Entity Framework error: Could not find the conceptual model type 

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

```
 public ViewResult List(string category,int page = 1)
    {
        ProductsListViewModel viewModel = new ProductsListViewModel
        {
            Products = repository.Products
            .Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category)
            .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
            .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize),

            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = category == null?repository.Products.Count():repository.Products.Where(e => e.Category == category).Count()
            },

            CurrentCategory = category
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

It throws an exception says that "Could not find the conceptual model type for SportsStore.Domain.Concrete.ORM.Product."
I guess it has something to do with the SportStore.edmx file which I add it manually ,but the book just metioned this file as if it is already exist, actually it not. So I have to create the ORM by myself, then the exception throwed . I don;t know how to check this problem,     thx..

Answer (score 0):

I was going through this book (Pro Asp.Net MVC 3 Framework) as well and found the same error/issue.

It seems like the author switched from using `ObjectContext` to 'DbContext' (or the other way around) and didn't clean up his examples.  The former is the older API from EntityFramework 4.0 and the latter is the API from 4.1.  `DbContext` is also just a wrapper for `ObjectContext` so they do the same things.

If you look at the code examples for Chapter 10 you can see he uses an Entity Data Model (.edmx) to make the connection between the database and the model whereas throughout the book up to that point he used the 'code-first' approach with `DbContext`.

The fact that this one section in Chapter 9 is the only time he mentions the `Concrete/ORM` folder and this .edmx Model gives further evidence to the idea that this is something left in from a previous iteration of the book.

To summarize: You don't need this .edmx model file, you don't need to update the conceptual model.  The framework should be able to connect the pieces of your `Product` model in code to the Product table in the database.

Here's a related question that might provide some insight:
[Using DbContext and Database First in EF 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264190/using-dbcontext-and-database-first-in-ef-4-1)