# Common Table Expression in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-4, common-table-expression

I have this query in Sql Server which I need to consume in EntityFramework, So how can I write a EntityFramwork code which will have the same result as this

```
WITH    cte AS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    StockGroups
        WHERE   GroupParent ='Stationery' 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  g.*
        FROM    StockGroups g
        JOIN    cte
        ON      g.GroupParent = cte.GroupName
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    cte
```

I don't know how to convert it in EF, so I tried with join.

```
from a in db.StockGroups
join b in db.StockGroups on new { GroupParent = a.GroupParent } equals new { GroupParent = b.GroupName }
where
  b.GroupName == "Stationery"
select new {
  a.GroupName,
  a.GroupParent,
  Column1 = b.GroupName,
  Column2 = b.GroupParent
}
```

But the result is not same, as recursive as CTE.

Answer (score 10):

EF does not support recursive CTE's. Use a view or a table valued function.

Comment: It is not Entity Framework. But it is right when EF cannot do something that you can do with sql query.

Answer (score 8):

Getting input [from the other experts over SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1757302/3195477), I have come up with my own way to achieve this.

```
IEnumerable<StockGroup> sg = dbContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<StockGroup>(
                        @"WITH    q AS
                                    (
                                    SELECT  *
                                    FROM    LedgerGroups
                                    WHERE   GroupParent = 'Customers'
                                    UNION ALL
                                    SELECT  m.*
                                    FROM    LedgerGroups m
                                    JOIN    q
                                    ON      m.GroupParent = q.GroupName
                                    )
                            SELECT  *
                            FROM    q
                        ");
```

Comment: Why bother using EF if you're going to execute raw SQL? IMO this is rather brittle. I'd recommend turning this query into a view and adding said view to your EF model.

Comment: @SouthShoreAK if `'Customer'` becomes a parameter, then this can't be converted to a view.

Comment: @SouthShoreAK Because many coders prefer code-version-control within application only. Maintaining Views adds more complexity. This should be stored in a Resource String. This answer still shows mapping to a class which is handy, easier than SqlDataReader.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use CTE recursion in Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Use stored procedure and call that stored procedure through EF

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is support for recursive CTEs in LINQ nor in EF. The solution is to expose the CTE as a view. The article on Recursive or hierarchical queries using EF Code First and Migrations shows how to deploy such a view using EF code first migrations. [Recursive or hierarchical queries using EF Code First and Migrations](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Recursive-or-hierarchical-bf43a96e)

Original source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11929928/3850405

Comment: Here is the revised location of the article mentioned:  https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-community-m-r/tree/master/Recursive%20or%20hierarchical%20queries%20using%20EF%20Code%20First%20and%20Migrations