# Why does my raw query to count rows always returns -1?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm trying to check if table exists, but not working correctly.

For some reason, count always returns -1.  I already have a table in the database. It
should return 1?

```
SearchEntities db = new SearchEntities();

var qry3 = "";
var sql4 = "SELECT Count(*) FROM SearchDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'portland'";
var count = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql4);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with EF but `ExecuteSqlCommand` is like `ExecuteNonQuery`? Maybe it always returns `-1` for a `SELECT` statement?

Comment: The count is appearing as the first column of the first row of the *result set* that your query generates. I don't think that that is what `ExecuteSqlCommand` is returning though - you want something similar to `ExecuteScalar` or some method that actually *returns* the result set to you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`ExecuteSqlCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) doesn't return data, it always returns an `Int32`, which is the number of rows processed by the SQL script when it's a `DDL/DML` command.

You want [`SqlQuery<TElement>(String, Object[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_Database_SqlQuery__1_System_String_System_Object___) instead.

```
var count = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql4).Single();
```

Answer (score 1):

[ExecuteStoreQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee358769(v=vs.100).aspx) Directly Execute Commands Against the Data Source.

```
int result = entity.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(@"
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'TableName') 
    SELECT 1
ELSE
    SELECT 0
").SingleOrDefault();
```

See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218489/check-if-a-table-exists-within-a-database-using-linq).

Comment: `ObjectContext`, while still available, is an older API. The `DbContext` API is recommended these days. [ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15875489/247702)